# Retrieve multiple phone contact labels on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts, addressbook

Ios allows to store multiple Home/ Mobile/ Work numbers for a contact. Is there a way to differentiate the two labels of Home phone number? We receive the label Home for all the home numbers. Is there a option there to differentiate Home1, Home2 etc. The following code just retrieves as Home/ work/ Mobile for all the respective phone numbers

```
for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones1); j++)
{      
  mobileLabel = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones1, j);
  if ([contactPhoneentry containsObject:mobileLabel]) 
  {
      continue;
  }

  if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
  {
     home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
     identstring = @"Mobile";
  }
  else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
  {
      home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
       identstring = @"iPhone";
  }
  else if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMainLabel])
  {
      home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
      identstring = @"Main";
  }
  else if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhonePagerLabel])
  {
      home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
      identstring = @"Pager";
  }
  else if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel])
  {
      home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
      identstring = @"Home Fax";
  }
  else if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel])
  {
      home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
      identstring = @"Work Fax";
  }
  else if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
  {
      home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
      identstring = @"Home";
  }
  else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
  {
       home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
       identstring = @"Work";
  }
  else
  {
       home_mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones1,j);
       identstring = @"Other";
  }
```

Is this right way to retrieve phone numbers and labels?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to accomplish, but you should not be using the label to distinguish one phone from another because, as you know, the labels are not unique.  Each value in a multiValueRef, in this case each phone number, has a unique identifier.  This identifier is unique to the other identifiers within the multi value, so you can use it to identifier phone numbers even if you have multiple numbers with the same label.

In your code above, you can get a phone numbers identifier by calling

```
int identifier = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones1, j);
```

It also looks like the code you posted is going to a lot of trouble to convert the label from address book into a localized label (i.e. '_$! < Work >!$_' to 'work').  The address book framework has a function to handle this for you - ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel().  For example -

```
NSString *localizedString = (__bridge NSString *)ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel);
```

This will set localizedString to "mobile".

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to distinguish the labels. IOS (and OSX) do not require uniqueness of labels in an `ABMultiValue`. It is fine to have multiple Home Phone numbers, for example. This also applies to addresses, emails, social profiles, etc.

Comment: Im doing a project where i group multiple contacts with their multiple phone numbers. When I select a Home(1) phone number to my group, it will be added to my app's group. If the user tends to remove the Home(1) phone number, it must be updated to app's group. Synchronization has became hard since there is no proper identification